# Will the full release of ASP.NET Web API be usable with VS2010?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-web-api

The beta of ASP.NET Web API is available and works fine with VS2010. Are there any indications that the full version, when released, will not be for any reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ASP.NET Web API will be compatible with VS2010 and .Net 4.  As far as I know :-)

Comment: Sorry. My line manager was spreading FUD. Scott Hanselman has confirmed it will remain .NET 4.